# Does the HP ProDesk 400 G3 support dual boot between Windows 10 & Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, hp, hardware

Recently purchased a refurbished HP ProDesk 400 G3 SFF PC Intel Quad-Core i5-6500 3.20GHz 16GB DDR4 1TB SSD DVDRW with Win10.

I wanted to have a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04, however, it seemed that the BIOS was corrupt and I couldn't change, or even view, boot order. While attempting to update the BIOS the machine died.

Went back to the supplier who is now telling me that they are not sure that this hardware will not support Ubuntu & Windows, well, they are asking me an I simply don't know. They hinted that there may be an issue with secure boot and Ubuntu.

I've not been able to find much online.

Would anyone have any guidance in this case?

1. Should the hardware support Ubuntu
2. Should the hardware support dual boot with Ubuntu & Windows
3. Any guidance as to why it won't support it if that's the case, so I know what to buy instead.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. YES
2. YES but probably with caveats. Some HP models always boot Windows by default but it's always possible to select another OS from the one-time boot menu.

Secure Boot has nothing to do with it and considering Windows 11 is out of the question due to hardware's age then Secure Boot can be disabled with any Windows 10 or older. But it doesn't have to be disabled as Ubuntu supports Secure Boot from the beginning.

Comment: Many thanks. They returned the machine with updated BIOS and I managed to install Ubuntu as dual boot with Windows.

Comment: Great news. You're welcome.